# Invert particular bits in a byte array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bit-manipulation, numpy-ndarray

what is the fastest way to invert particular bits in all of the bytes within a byte array? I want to invert bits on these positions 0b00110011. Now I am doing it this way but for long array it's pretty slow.

```
for i in range(len(byte_array_np)):
    byte_array_np[i] &= 0x77
    byte_array_np[i] ^= 0x33
```

Thank you for sugestions.

Comment: How about just `byte_array_np &= 0x77; byte_array_np ^= 0x33`?

Comment: What's with the AND? You only need XOR to invert, no?